1-loop renormalization for interacting scalar theory - choice of the subtraction point
I would like to clarify some things about interacting scalar fields. In particlar I am having trouble with subtraction points in 1 loop renormalization of the theory.
The lagrangian for 2 interacting massless real scalar fields in 4 dimensions is
$$ \mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi_1 \partial^\mu\phi_2 + \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi_2 \partial^\mu\phi_1 +\frac{\lambda}{4!} (\phi_1^4+\phi_2^4) +\frac{2\rho}{4!}\phi_1^2\phi_2^2. $$
This theory has $SO(2)$ invariance, if as suggested in the comments, $\lambda=\rho$; in this case it can be mapped into the complex massless scalar theory:
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi^*+\frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi^2\phi^{*2})^2$$
by using a linear combination of degrees of freedom. Anyway this is not the case, so $\lambda \neq \rho$.
The theory is renormalizable in d=4 and I only expect divergences to appear (at any order in loop) for the 2- and the 4-point functions. Moreover since we are dealing with a massless theory, tadpoles are vanishing, if we decide to work in dimensional regularization; for this reason I do not care about the renormalization of the propagators.
I would like to compute the 1-loop contributions to the 4-point functions; in order to do so i produce a set of Feynman rules that contains 3 types of vertices, two of them are proportional to $\lambda$ and a third which is proportional to $\rho$.
In general I expect to find, at 1-loop, contributions to the 4-point function that contain both the couplings.
Following the notes of my prof I expect to find renormalized quantities (in euclidean signature):
$$\Gamma^{(4)}_{\phi_1^4}=-\lambda$$
$$\Gamma^{(4)}_{\phi_2^4}=-\lambda$$
$$\Gamma^{(4)}_{\phi_1^2\phi_2^2}=-2\rho$$
where we choose the subtraction point:
$$s=t=u=\Lambda^2$$
by imposing (i now quote the prof.) "by imposing that when we compute the
vertices at this sub. pt. the result has to coincide with the tree level result".\
Here is were I got lost!
For what I understand this sub. point is the one that gives the same expression for the divergent part of the three different channels.
But why do I want the finite part to vanish at the subtraction point ? (I understand this for the propagator, since the mass have to be the pole of the propagator, but here ?)
I did the computation in dimensional regularization of the 1 loop contributions to the 4 point function of the first kind:
$$\Gamma_{\phi_1^4} = k^{2\epsilon}(\frac{3\lambda^2}{32\pi^2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+log(s^2 / 4\pi K^2)+2-\gamma)+\frac{3\lambda\rho}{16\pi^2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+log(s^2 / 4\pi K^2)+2-\gamma))$$
where the two terms refers to the two type of topologies and the 3 is given by the sum over the 3 different channels (given the same subtraction point for the three topologies, as I was saying);
Moreover in my conventions $d=4-2\epsilon$.
My questions are:
Now i have my results at 1 loop, here i have chosen a subtraction point and i have computed the integrals with their finite parts; what do I have to do now ?
I would like to compute the beta function now but i need to work in the minimal subtraction "scheme" which means that counterterms only contains the divergent part of green functions.
But if i only subtract the divergent part when defining renormalized parameters i expect to find a finite correction to the coupling; it seems to me that by imposing that AT the sub. pt the finite part vanishes fixes in some sense a particular value of the subtraction point as a function of the scale K (since the finite part depend on K).
Is this a right interpretation ?
Do I always need to choose the finite part to vanish at the sub. pt. in general ?
This is part of the resolution of an exercise on Peskin & Schroeder (An introduction to quantum field theory) at page 438 n. 12.3
I excuse for the confusion on this topic.

No, you can't map your SO(2) theory to a single complex scalar unless $\lambda = \rho$.

For $\lambda \neq \rho$, it's just not $SO(2)$ invariant to begin with.

Thank you, yes the theory is not even invariant if $\lambda\neq\rho$; can you clarify more on the choice of the subtraction point ? to me it seems a general pattern in renormalization theory (the one described above). What is not clear to me is why the finite contributions to the coupling disappear when i choose that particular subtraction point. Thank you in advance
